# Parking Simulation

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to run a parking simulation. I keep getting a few errors. If you could take a look and maybe explain what I'm missing.

```
void ParkingTicket::generateticket() const
{
    ParkedCar  car("GMC","Yukon XL","Grey","111111",9999);
    PoliceOfficer bacon("Blake Peebles",9999);               
    ParkingMeter pm(55);

    if (car.getNumMinutes() > pm.getTP())
    {
        double time4fine = car.getNumMinutes() - pm.getTP();
        double fine;
```

The errors I'm getting are:

> In member function 'void ParkingTicket::generateticket() const':
>   Line 187 expected ; before car

any help would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: I would start by trying to find the smallest piece of code that still exhibits the problem. You usually find the cause of the problem in the attempt. I'd also pay particular attention to the syntax of line 187.

Comment: Thanks pamphlet, I cut the code down on here. I'm just not sure why it's expecting a ; before car.

Comment: You might want to tell us which line *is* line 187.

Comment: Are you certain that `ParkedCar` is visible from here ?

Comment: I didn't mean show us less code, I meant show the compiler less code.

Comment: You seem to have member functions that shadow the other class names. Remove those entirely; they *prevent* you from (normally) making instances of those classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you need it's just:

```
::ParkedCar car("GMC","Yukon XL","Grey","111111",9999);
::PoliceOfficer bacon("Blake Peebles",9999);
::ParkingMeter pm(55);
```

The source of problems is the same names of classes and member-functions.

Comment: I highly doubt the member functions are supposed to be there. If I'm correct, a much better solution would be getting rid of them.